# How to apply WebClient.attribute on every webflux request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactor, spring-webclient

I have a `WebClient` created with `WebClient.Builder` from `spring-webflux`.

I want to hand over a specific parameter (here `MDC.get("uuid")`) into *every* request that is executed using that `WebClient`. It could be done as follows:

```
webClient.get().attribute(ClientRequest.LOG_ID_ATTRIBUTE, MDC.get("uuid"))....block();
```

But: I'd prefer adding this attribute already during the `WebClient.Builder` process, eg as an `ExchangeFilter` or similar. So that every class that makes use of my default common builder will automatically set this attribute, without having to call it explicit on each web request.

Is that possible?

Comment: you cannot use MDC the way you are using it in a webflux application due to the fact that MDC uses `threadlocal` to store data. `Threadlocal` cannot be used since reactive programming is thread agnostic. As soon as the reactive context switches thread, the MDC will be empty. You need to use the reactive `context` instead. But it is impossible to give advice until we understand the purpose of WHY you want to pass an uuid in every request. And where this uuid is passed into the mdc.

Comment: The `ClientRequest.LOG_ID_ATTRIBUTE` attribute is afaik, evaluated by spring in different situations. If not set, spring will generate a random id. But as it is then hard to track my logs, I'm passing the same uuid that I use for loggin *outside* the webflux context. So whatever I log inside webflux reactive, I can extract the `LOG_ID_ATTRIBUTE` from context and insert it into my log statement. That's why I want to pass that uuid on every webclient execution by default.